# How can we *set* deadlines, to allow us to work to them effectively, in an agile way?

Tags: project-management, agile, estimation, deadlines

I'm working in a team that's been consistently and fairly successfully working in an agile approach, and this has been working great for the current project until now, for our initial work, as we incrementally build the product.

We're now moving into the next phase of this though, and the management are keen for us to set some specific deadlines ourselves, for when we'll be in a position to demo and sell this to real customers, on the order of months.

We have a fairly well organised large backlog for each of the elements of functionality we'd like to include, and a good sense of the prioritisation of these individual bits of functionality.

The naive solution is to get the minimum list of stories that would provide a demo-able product, estimate all of those individually, and add them up and combine with our velocity to get a date, and announce we'll be demoing from then. That leaves no leeway though, and seems likely to result in a mad crunch as we get up to deadline time, which I desperately want to avoid.

As an improvement, I'd like to add in some ratio of more optional stories to act as either contingency or bonus improvements, depending on how we progress, but we don't have any idea what ratio would be sensible, or whether this is the standard approach.

I'm also concerned by having to estimate the whole of our backlog all in one go up-front, as that seems very time consuming, and it seems likely that we'll discover more information in the months before we get to that story, which will affect our estimates.

Are there recommended approaches to dealing with setting deadlines to allow for an agile development process? Most of the information I've seen seems to be around handling the situation once you've got a fixed deadline to hit instead. I'd also be interested in any relevant literature or interesting blog posts that cover this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding literature: the best book I know regarding the estimation in software is "Software Estimation: Demystifying the Black Art" by Steve McConnel. It covers your case. Plus, it describes the difference between *estimation* and *commitment* (set-deadline, in other words) and explains how to derive the second from the first reliably.

Answer (score 1):

> The naive solution is to get the minimum list of stories that would
>   provide a demo-able product, estimate all of those individually, and
>   add them up and combine with our velocity to get a date, and announce
>   we'll be demoing from then. That leaves no leeway though, and seems
>   likely to result in a mad crunch as we get up to deadline time, which
>   I desperately want to avoid.

This is the solution I have used in the past.  Your initial estimate is going to be off a bit so add some slack via a couple of additional sprints before setting your release date.  If you get behind you can make it up in the slack.  If not, your product backlog gives you additional features that you can include in the release if you so choose.  This will be dependent on your velocity metric for the team though.  Adjust your slack based on how accurate you feel this metric is for the current team.  Once you have a target release you can circle back to see if you have any known resource constraints that might affect that release.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you describe is likely to be correct. You may want to estimate for all desirable features, and prioritise UI elements (because investors and customers basically just see the shiny UI), and then your deadline will be that estimated date for completion; then add on some slack in the form of scaling your estimates. Use the ratio between current productivity and your worst period to create a pessimistic estimate. You can use that same ratio to scale shorter estimates (e.g. for your estimate to the minimum feature set).